# How to Join two tables in bookshelfjs in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

I Have two tables in MySQl DB which are:

**Customer:**

> - cust_ID (PK)
> - cust_name
> - trans_ID (FK)

**Transaction**

> - trans_id (PK)
> - trans_amount

In Node.js I have created the two models for both of these tables , Now i want to do Inner Join on both these table based on trans_id. I am not getting the Idea to how to do.

```
var Transaction = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'Transaction'
});

var Customer = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'Customer'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bookshelf.js beginner myself, but if I'm not mistaken, bookshelf.js abstracts away the notion of inner joins. Instead, if your question can be translated as 'how do I get a transaction/transactions and their related customers?' the answer would be something like this:

transaction.js:

```
var Transaction = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'Transaction',
    customers: function() {
        return this.hasMany(Customer, 'trans_ID');
    }
});
```

customer.js:

```
var Customer = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'Customer',
   transaction: function() {
       return this.belongsTo(Transaction, 'trans_ID');
   }
});
```

To get a transaction with all its related customers you do something like this:

```
new Transaction()
    .where('trans_id', 1)
    .fetch({withRelated: ['customers']})
    .then(function(theTransaction) {
       var arrayOfCustomers = theTransaction.customers;
       //...
    });
```

Please see bookshelf.js's documentation for [hasMany](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-hasMany) and [belongsTo](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-belongsTo) for further information.

I hope this answer was in the ballpark of what you were looking for.

Comment: And it will be a multiple chained separated queries, not a join.